# Удалять добавленные фото

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, retrofit

Есть метод, где по нажатию на кнопку, есть возможность добавлять фото из камеры/галлереи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После добавления фотографий, необходимо добавить возможность их удалять.

Размышляю следующим образом, если ошибаюсь, поправьте меня пожалуйста(вопрос откорректирую).

1. Необходимо добавить элемент *circle*(обычный крестик) к добавленной фотографии.
2. По нажатию на крестик в фрагменте приложения, отработать метод `remove`? (Где лучше этот метод прописать?)

Comment: ну вы попробуйте хотя бы для начала. Ваш подход правильный, я думаю ответ "Да" не совсем достоин быть написан как ответ...

Comment: @metalurgus вот думаю с какой стороны лучше зайти(т.к. проект не маленький и много разных дополнений), чтоб более правильно откорректировать вопрос.